# Importing another Package as a Dependency in SPM into another Package, with Swift 5.1

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

So im using SPM (Swift Package Manager) to create my own package library. I wanted to import another package into my package, to use, as shown below:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftRecommendations",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .macOS(.v10_13),
        .tvOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SwiftRecommendations",
            targets: ["SwiftRecommendations"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-log.git",
            .branch("master")
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SwiftRecommendations",
            dependencies: ["Logging"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SwiftRecommendationsTests",
            dependencies: ["SwiftRecommendations", "Logging"]),
    ]
)
```

Im trying to import and run Logger inside my test file, but it complains that **No such module Logger** after I add the import statement. I can see in my Xcode the Swift Package Dependencies is showing `swift-log`, so not sure what's going on.

My test class is as follows:

```
import XCTest
import Logger
@testable import SwiftRecommendations

final class SwiftRecommendationsTests: XCTestCase {

    static var tokenService: TokenService?
    var logger: Logger?


    override func setUp(){
        super.setUp()
        self.logger = Logger(label: "com.samba.tv.recommendations")


    }
```

Comment: Can you show your import? Shouldn't the import called Logging?

Comment: @Robin I updated the code to show my import statement.

Comment: According to the [library instructions from Apple](https://github.com/apple/swift-log) it should be Logging. An interesting fact, in my normal target (not testing) it doesn't complain.

Comment: Actually @robin embarrassing but you are right the import statement is wrong.. Sorry too long in front of screen. Embarrassing :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh I did actually have the wrong import statement. Really sorry... :( It should be `import Logging` not `import Logger`.